# pygtk - B1() takes only 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I am working with PyGTK and when I try to bind the signals of my GUI (which is just one button written in XML using Glade) to functions, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: B1() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here is my Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('/home/jatin/button.glade')
        self.MainWindow = self.builder.get_object('GW1')
        if self.MainWindow:
            self.MainWindow.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

        dic = {
            'on_B1_clicked' : self.B1,
            'on_B2_clicked' : self.B2,
            'on_B3_clicked' : self.B3
        }
        self.builder.connect_signals(dic)
    def B1(self):
        return('ham')

    def B2(self):
        return('ham')

    def B3(self):
        return('ham')


M = Main()
gtk.main()
```

Here is my Glade file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="GW1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="GB1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="B1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_B1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="B2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="B3">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

The interesting part is that if I change the number of argumets passed in, the error message changes like this:

With zero arguments:

```
TypeError: B1() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

With 2 arguments I get no error but the function doesn't do what it's supposed to. And with 3 or more arguments:

```
TypeError: B1() takes 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I'll do that next time. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: I've never even heard of the libraries you're using. Where is `B1` being called? I suspect the library is trying to pass in an explicit argument, even though your methods only take implicit `self`s.

Comment: This is a GUI library. If you have Linux, save the XML file as button.glade and the python file as button.py and it'll launch a window with three button. In the dict, I'm defining that when button 1 is pressed (labeled B1), execute the function B1.

Comment: The callback gets two arguments. `self` and the widget that emitted the signal, in this case a button. Your return statement does not work. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Side note, you are importing pygtk and pygobject, don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each signal has certain arguments that are passed into connected signal handlers. Look in the documentation to see what they are. For example, you can see that [`Gtk.Button`'s `clicked` signal](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#Gtk.Button.signals.clicked) receives the button itself as an argument.

Your signal handler's number of arguments must match those arguments, as well as include `self` if it's a method. So, the correct definition for `B1` would be:

```
def B1(self, button):
```

In some cases you really might not care about the values passed into the signal handler. In that case, you can do something like:

```
def B1(self, *args):
```

This is explained [here](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.connect) in the documentation.